# Excel to Python Dictionary for Filtering with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm trying to read an excel file to store the selected columns into a python dictionary. For further data filtering and manipulation. I consulted a lot of Stackoverflow existing questions to get the pointers. However I'm able to figure out few things. But having no prior experience with Python giving me some real challenges. Can I ask for your help please? Following is the code which I was able to make it work up to some extent.

```
from _collections import defaultdict
import openpyxl

SalesFunnel = defaultdict(list)

theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('Report.xlsx')
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames

print("All sheet names {} " .format(theFile.sheetnames))

for sheet in allSheetNames:
    print("Current sheet name is {}" .format(sheet))
    currentSheet = theFile[sheet]


sfunnel = []


for row in range(1, currentSheet.max_row + 1):
    for column in "ADEF":  
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        SalesFunnel[row] = [cell_name, currentSheet[cell_name].value]
        SalesFunnel[row].append(SalesFunnel[row])
    print(SalesFunnel)
```

My excel dataset contains duplicate emails and the duplicate lead statuses. Each row contains a created Date. I need to find out the max and min of the date for each email within a lead status. So that I can compute the days in between for each email address. But for now I'm unable to read the data in a correct format. I also added a column for the unique index which is simply the number sequence to uniquely identify each row.

If I got something like that in a json format. It would be great.

```
{Index: 1, LeadStatus: Contacted, Email: joe@doe.com, CreatedDate: 7/9/2020}
{Index: 2, LeadStatus: Contacted, Email: joe@doe.com, CreatedDate: 8/10/2020}
{Index: 3, LeadStatus: Contacted, Email: joe@doe.com, CreatedDate: 9/11/2020}
{Index: 4, LeadStatus: Contacted, Email: ron@email.com, CreatedDate: 4/5/2020}
{Index: 5, LeadStatus: Contacted, Email: ron@email.com, CreatedDate: 7/6/2020}
```

Also adding a screenshot of my excel sheet. You can only see one email because I have thousands of records. And for each email there could be many records. And Lead Status could be something other than Contacted.

[image]

Comment: Is it a must to read your data with `openpyxl`? You can read with `pandas`, it'd be easy to add the min and max plus the difference and then you can store in a json format if you like

Comment: @Kay Honestly, it doesn't matter for me. All I need is to read the data and perform my calculations. And I'm still stuck to step 1 :)

Comment: I don't know which how your spreadsheet is structured, but you can read the data like this:
`import pandas as pd` `pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name, skiprows=[0,1,2], usecols='A:F')` Use `skiprows` if your data doesn't start in cell `A1` and you have to skip some rows. In the code above, we are skipping the first, second and third rows and then reading from columns `A` to `F`. If your data starts in cell `A1` and you want to read everything, then just providing `file_path` and `sheet_name` should be fine.

Comment: Let me try with this too. I don't have pandas installed already.

Comment: If you could provide an image of the spreadsheet or a sample of the data, you might get help quicker.

Comment: @Kay I added the screenshot of my excel sheet. There are multiple emails with different lead status and it doesn't matter. I just need to extract the max and min date for each email with a specific lead status. And then calculate days that lead took in each status.

Comment: See my answer below!

Comment: I'm installing pandas. If this is going to solve the problem. I'm definitely going to learn the python and pandas for sure :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the data using `pandas`. I am assuming your data starts from cell `A1` and you are reading everything in the sheet.

```
data_df = pd.read_excel(sheet_path, sheet_name)
```

Now you can calculate the `max` and `min` dates for each group and find your differences

```
data_df['MaxDate'] = data_df.groupby(['LeadStatus','Email'])['CreatedDate'].transform('max')
data_df['MinDate'] = data_df.groupby(['LeadStatus','Email'])['CreatedDate'].transform('min')
data_df['Difference'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['MaxDate']) - pd.to_datetime(data_df['MinDate'])
```

If you don't want to repeat records, use `agg`

```
agg_df = data_df.groupby(['LeadId','LeadStatus','Email']).agg(MaxDate=('CreatedDate','max'),
                     MinDate = ('CreatedDate', 'min')).reset_index()
agg_df['Difference'] = pd.to_datetime(agg_df['MaxDate']) - pd.to_datetime(agg_df['MinDate'])
```

You can now convert to `json` if you like:

```
data_df.to_json(orient='records')
```

You can also write to excel

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('..../new_doc.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:

    data_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='New Data', index=False)
    agg_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Agg Data', index=False)
```

Comment: Is it possible to write a new spreadsheet, which gives me same structure with the same columns but only with the computed values. Like the LeadId, Email, Status and the computed days. Or it would be best if I can see the max and min dates too, for each record.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It is working perfectly. There's only one issue. It would be cool if we don't repeat all the rows. For example as you can see my screenshot above. It should have to become one single record with the max, min and difference plus all the existing values. Is that possible?

Comment: I saw an answer to my question on another stackoverflow. But I'd love if you post it here for the sake of completeness and one single clean copy of your code. It would help greatly to new users in future.

Comment: I added what you asked. I thought you wanted to keep the structure of the data and add the new columns. If not, use the option with `agg`. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Kay. Can I have you as my mentor for learning python? ☺

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou Yeah sure.

Comment: Please share your social media handle or whatever place you feel will be suitable to ask directly to you. Thanks.